# How do I calculate Turnaround rate (%) in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am creating a SSRS report and one of the requirements of the report is to display ‘Turnaround Rate’ which is supposed to contain values in percentage.

Some of the columns from my dataset are like:-

```
DateReceived
DateCompleted
CompleteTurnaround
TurnaroundVolume
MaximumTurnaroundDays
TurnaroundInMonth
TurnaroundInStandard
```

I’ve done an extensive research on the topic and haven’t found a solution yet. Also absolutely lost here and would really appreciate any help with this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: We can help you implement an expression in reporting services, but not explain what turnaround rate is and how to calculate it.

Comment: Show some sample data that you have to work with, what your expected result based on that sample data would be and explain how you achieved it. Also state if any of the calculations will be on aggregated data (i.e. grouped totals etc) as this will impact how the expression is built.

Answer (score 0):

I think a Turnaround Rate would be based upon records that were completed within the **Standard** amount of time as indicated in the TurnaroundInStandard column.

Assuming there's one record per and your grouping them, it should be the records that were complete within the standard amount of time (TurnaroundInStandard = 1 or Y, depending on the field) divided by the number of total number of ones that are complete (CompleteTurnaround = 1 or Y). If so, then your expression would be:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!CompleteTurnaround.Value = "Y", 1, 0)) 
 /
 SUM(IIF(Fields!TurnaroundInStandard.Value = "Y", 1, 0))
```